# H2: can't initialize DB schema from an sql file inside a jar

Tags: java, database, exception, h2

I am trying to use the H2 database (*v1.3.170*) for JUnit testing in my project and experiencing a weird behavior.
I have one jar containing all sqls for DB schema initialization:

```
db_data.jar
  |--schema
        |--aliases.sql
        |--tables.sql
        |-- ...
```

I have this jar in my classpath. But when I am executing the below code - it throws an exception [see below]:

```
CallableStatement initCall = conn.prepareCall("RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:schema/aliases.sql'");
initCall.execute();
```

The exception thown:

```
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "java.io.FileNotFoundException: resource /schema/aliases.sql"; "classpath:schema/aliases.sql"; SQL statement:
RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath:schema/aliases.sql' [90031-170]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:329)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:158)
    at org.h2.message.DbException.convertIOException(DbException.java:315)
    at org.h2.command.dml.ScriptBase.openInput(ScriptBase.java:162)
    at org.h2.command.dml.RunScriptCommand.update(RunScriptCommand.java:43)
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:75)
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:230)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.process(TcpServerThread.java:333)
    at org.h2.server.TcpServerThread.run(TcpServerThread.java:149)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: resource /schema/aliases.sql
    at org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk.newInputStream(FilePathDisk.java:285)
    at org.h2.store.fs.FileUtils.newInputStream(FileUtils.java:209)
    at org.h2.command.dml.ScriptBase.openInput(ScriptBase.java:160)
    ... 6 more
```

I saw that in `org.h2.store.fs.FilePathDisk#newInputStream()` you are explicitly adding the `/` to the path of the SQL file:

```
public InputStream newInputStream() throws IOException {
    //...
    if (!fileName.startsWith("/")) {
        fileName = "/" + fileName;
    }
    //...
    return in;
}
```

Can you please explain the purpose of the above? And how to deal with the exception?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try `'classpath:/schema/aliases.sql'` (slash in front). If it doesn't work, what is your database URL? (The jar file needs to be on the server side when using the server mode.)

Comment: you are right Thomas. The issue was that the aliases.sql was in the client classpath and was not in the TCP server classpath.  
Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! I have added the solution as an answer now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resource (jar file) needs to be on the server side when using the server mode.

Answer (score -1):

Try changing the file reference to:

```
classpath*:schema/aliases.sql
```

Comment: That doesn't work:
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLException: IO Exception: "java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: classpath*:schema/aliases.sql"; "classpath*:schema/aliases.sql"; SQL statement:
RUNSCRIPT FROM 'classpath*:schema/aliases.sql' [90031-170]